# how to stop seaborn visualisation sorting the values on the X axis of a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, seaborn

I have a column in a pandas dataframe called month_name which contains some months of the year.

I have tried feeding this data to seaborn visualisation library as both an object and categorical datatype.

I have also tried sorting the list before I pass it to seaborn library. In Both Instances the resulting graph looks like (with the month_name out of order:

```
         150           105                   _ 147_
Y-amount 100   47     ____     38    33      |    |
         50  ____     |   |  _____  ____     |    |
         0   |   |    |   |  |    | |   |    |    |
             |   |    |   |  |    | |   |    |    |
                     X-month_name
             August   July   June  October  September
```

**How do I get the month_names to appear in the correct order**

**And have the actual exact value on top of the bar like in the year example over [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/cs109/content/blob/master/lec_03_statistical_graphs.ipynb) which is just above the DOT PLOT example**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the new `pd.Categorical` type in `seaborn`, which is currently not supported, but is slated for addition in version `0.6.0`. See this github issue: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/361

Comment: Is there some kind of workaround in the meantime? It's important to me that the months are displayed in order. it really messes with the readability of the data otherwise. Is the workaround possibly to either 1) use seaborn and put up with it or 2) use another visualisation library in the meantime.

Comment: I love the COL parameter of the seaborn factorplot and some other plots - it makes it so easy to plot multiple dimensions which is why it would be hard to move just because it doesn't sort categorical.

Comment: even though seaborn at the moment doesn't display categorical data correctly --> does seaborn have the ability to display the exact data values on top of the bars in the bar chart? And if so how does one achieve this with a factorplot and other seaborn plots?

Comment: My workaround is to just plot with matplotlib for now. As far as I understand the pandas/seaborn development cycles, you'll have to wait for the 0.6.0 to get the categorical order. Sucks there's no better solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

```
{x, hue, col, row}_order : list-like, optional
    Order of levels plotted on various dimensions of the figure.
    Default is to use sorted level values.
```